# Centos - Virtualmin Package Updates - mysql update error because of conflicts with file from different package. Any safe solution?

Tags: mysql, centos, yum, webmin

When I try to apply Virtualmin Package Updates - **mysql updates** on Centos 5.5 64-bit - it returns **install failed because of conflicts with file from different package**.

When I try `yum remove mysql*` or `yum remove mysql.i386` and after fresh mysql install trough Virtualmin Package Updates or `yum install mysql` mess up something and returns error - does not work.

Any advice how to solve it?

```
Now updating mysql ..
Installing package(s) with command yum -y install mysql ..
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.anl.gov
 * centosplus: pubmirrors.reflected.net
 * contrib: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Reducing CentOS-5 - Plus to included packages only
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: mysql-devel
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: dovecot
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: dovecot
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) for package: mysql-devel
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: mysql-server
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.52-jason.1 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.52-jason.1 set to be updated
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.52-jason.1 set to be updated
---> Package mysqlclient15.x86_64 0:5.0.91-1.jason.1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package            Arch        Version               Repository           Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 mysql              x86_64      5.1.52-jason.1        utterramblings      3.5 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mysqlclient15      x86_64      5.0.91-1.jason.1      utterramblings      2.0 M
Updating for dependencies:
 mysql-devel        x86_64      5.1.52-jason.1        utterramblings      120 k
 mysql-server       x86_64      5.1.52-jason.1        utterramblings       13 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       3 Package(s)

Total size: 18 M
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386

Error Summary
-------------

.. install failed!

Now updating mysql-server ..
Installing package(s) with command yum -y install mysql-server ..
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.anl.gov
 * centosplus: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * contrib: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Reducing CentOS-5 - Plus to included packages only
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.52-jason.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.1.52-jason.1 for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: dovecot
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: mysql-devel
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: dovecot
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) for package: mysql-devel
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.52-jason.1 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.52-jason.1 set to be updated
---> Package mysqlclient15.x86_64 0:5.0.91-1.jason.1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package            Arch        Version               Repository           Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 mysql-server       x86_64      5.1.52-jason.1        utterramblings       13 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mysqlclient15      x86_64      5.0.91-1.jason.1      utterramblings      2.0 M
Updating for dependencies:
 mysql              x86_64      5.1.52-jason.1        utterramblings      3.5 M
 mysql-devel        x86_64      5.1.52-jason.1        utterramblings      120 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       3 Package(s)

Total size: 18 M
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.52-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386

Error Summary
-------------

.. install failed!

No packages were installed. Check the messages above for the cause of the error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened bug in http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3383193&group_id=17457&atid=117457

**Update:** The conflict was cased because of yum repositories. After removing some, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First erase all mysql packages (regardless of units) and disable all non-official yum repositories except the Virtualmin.

rpm -e --nodeps mysql*

After this run installer of Virtualmin.